# ansible - changing a specific line in configuration file using a jinja template

Tags: linux, deployment, ansible, configuration, jinja2

I have an .ini config file that I'd like to template, but I only want to manipulate one or two lines with the jinja2 files.

example config file:

```sh
[configuration]
config1 = this_is_fine
config2 = to_be_templated
config3 = to_be_templated
config_4 = this_is_fine
```

What would be the best way to define a configuration.ini.j2 that would only change

```
config2 = {{ assigned_value }}
config3 = {{ assigned_value }}
```

while keeping the formatting and remaining configuration in place when running the playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**Manipulate one or two lines with the Jinja2 files.**"*

A: *"One or two lines"* means a **block**. Use [*blockinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-blockinfile-insert-update-remove-a-text-block-surrounded-by-marker-lines) to manipulate a block in a file. You'll need *markers* to do this, e.g. given the file

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini
[configuration]
config1 = this_is_fine
config2 = to_be_templated
config3 = to_be_templated
config_4 = this_is_fine
```

the two tasks below put markers around the block starting *config2* and ending *config3*

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: conf.ini
        regexp: '(config2.*)'
        replace: |-
          {{ '#' }} BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
          \g<1>
    - replace:
        path: conf.ini
        regexp: '(config2.*[\s\S]*?config3.*)'
        replace: |-
          \g<1>
          {{ '#' }} END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini
[configuration]
config1 = this_is_fine
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
config2 = to_be_templated
config3 = to_be_templated
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
config_4 = this_is_fine
```

These two tasks are not idempotent. Run them only once. Either put them in a separate playbook to set up the project or test the presence of the markers.

Now you can use the template

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini.j2
config2 = {{ assigned_value }}
config3 = {{ assigned_value }}
```

For example, the task below

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        path: conf.ini
        marker: '# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3'
        block: |
          {{ lookup('template', 'conf.ini.j2') }}
      vars:
        assigned_value: AVALUE
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini
[configuration]
config1 = this_is_fine
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
config2 = AVALUE
config3 = AVALUE
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK c2-3
config_4 = this_is_fine
```